# Azure Notification Hub : Count is not updated in Active Device limit count after delete registration from backend

Tags: azure, push-notification, notifications, limit, azure-notificationhub

I am using

await hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration.RegistrationId,registration.ETag);

Method to deleteregistration from azure notification hub manually but it is not updating count of active device limit in notification hub.

How to delete limit count in hub?

Anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right - it just can take up to 24 hours for the number of devices associated with your namespace/hub to update in the portal.

Comment: Yes you are totally correct! Thank you so much for you valuable reply.